# items of listbox losing styles after postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a ListBox. When I bind data I need to distinguish some items by color. There is how I do it

```
Protected Sub ListBox_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim lb As ListBox = CType(sender, ListBox)

    For Each li As ListItem In lb.Items
        If someFlag = True Then
            li.Attributes("style") += "color: red;"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

But when I do postback these styles is lost. How I can save style between postback?
**EDIT:** Inside Page_Load I don't do anything with this listbox. I fill listbox when occur event selectIndexChange for ddl. but when I click on linkbutton

```
Private Sub lnkbtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lnkBtn.Click
    Dim selectedItems As ArrayList = New ArrayList
    For Each itm As ListItem In listbox1.Items
        If itm.Selected = True Then
            selectedItems.Add(itm)
        End If
    Next

    For i As Int32 = 0 To selectedItems.Count - 1
        listbox1.Items.Remove(selectedItems(i))
        listbox2.Items.Add(selectedItems(i))
    Next
End Sub
```

after this event items of listbox1 lost styles

Comment: Show your Page_Load event please

Comment: Seems to be something n Page_Load, maybe you need to test If Not Page.IsPostBack then ...

Comment: I added some information

Comment: Is `listbox1` the one that losing styles?

Comment: listbox1 only one who have this styles and one that losing styles

Comment: Check if the listBox1 ViewState property is enabled or not.

Comment: Yes, ViewState is enable